# Не приходит письмо после создания пользователя

Tags: php, wordpress

Пытаюсь создать заказ программно с помощью `$order = wc_create_order();`
Также одновременно создается пользователь с помощью этого кода:

```
    $userdata = array(
        'user_login' => $user_name,
        'user_pass'  => $password,
        'user_email' => $email,
        'display_name' => $data['address']['last_name'] . ' ' . $data['address']['first_name']
    );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;
```

но не приходит письмо этому пользователю с логином и паролем.
проверял, пользователь в базе создаётся.
А письмо о успешном создании заказа пользователю приходит.

Где это можно настроить, чтобы приходили письма с паролем?
В настройках `woocommerce` выбрано чтобы можно было создавать личный кабинет и регистрироваться

**P.S.**

```
    $password = wp_generate_password();
    $user_name = strstr($email, '@', true);
    $userdata = array(
        'user_login' => $user_name,
        'user_pass'  => $password,
        'user_email' => $email,
        'display_name' => $data['address']['last_name'] . ' ' . $data['address']['first_name']
    );
    $user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;
```

Answer (score 1):

В ваш код после строки `$user_id = wp_insert_user( $userdata ) ;` добавьте

```
    $message = 'Your login: ' . $user_name . '. Your password: ' . $password;
    wp_mail( $email, 'Login & pass', $message );
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте через Mailer();

```
$woocommerce->mailer()->emails['WC_Email_Customer_New_Account']->customer_new_account($userId);
```

Код не проверял, в теории должно работать. Если ошибся где-то, дайте знать, исправлю.

И удачи! :)

Comment: обновил вопрос, подскажите, если я генерирую пароль с помощью `$password = wp_generate_password();`, как этот пароль отправлять на почту? Может я не правильно создаю пользователя?

Comment: получилось так отправить `WC()->mailer()->customer_new_account($user_id);`, но пришёл только логин. Что неправильно?